# iphone X Camera Preset?

Tags: camera, video-sequence-editor

Hi I'm shooting on an iPhone X trying to track my footage. I don't know the iPhone X's camera info and am having trouble finding info that looks like should be putting into blender.

If you have the information please post or point me in the right direction to go. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use your favorite search engine to find the dimensions of the camera sensor and lens used in your device, Then type them into the  Sensor and Lens settings for motion tracking in the Movie Clip editor. To make a new preset just press the Plus sign on the camera presets so that you can use it for future projects.